# visual studio 2017 goto method in file

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I am trying to use VS 2017 on my typescript project. I am using the `goto` member and trying to navigate to methods in my current file. However, VS 2017 does not seem to filter the methods properly. In the `goto` I am using **"m and currentfile"** and for example, if I try to filter **"extractData"**, it does not seem to filter properly.

My `.ts` file is as follows.

```
export class FooterLinksServiceSiteCore implements FooterLinksService {

/**
 *  
 * @param {Http} private http [description]
 */
constructor(private http: Http) {

}

/**
 * [LoadFooterLinks description]
 * @return {Observable<FooterLink[]>} [description]
 */
get(footerValuesLink: string): Observable<FooterLink[]> {
}

/**
 * [extractData description]
 * @param {Response} res [description]
 */
private extractData(res: Response): Array<FooterLink> {
    let mappedFooterLinks: Array<FooterLink> = new Array<FooterLink>();
    let footerLinks = res.json();
    footerLinks.forEach(footerLink => {
        mappedFooterLinks.push(new FooterLink(footerLink.Title, footerLink.Url));
    });
    return mappedFooterLinks;
}

/**
 * [handleError description]
 * @param {Response | any} error [description]
 */
private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
        const body = error.json() || '';
        const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
        errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
        errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }

}
```

Comment: VS 2017 is beta - this might be a bug.

Comment: Actually istn't it RC?

Comment: you are right..

Comment: And since this is basic functionality shouldn't this work? or am I missing something here?

Comment: See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6209 does this apply to your problem? Could be another implementation issue with typescript similar to the one in the link